# Mem alloced via mmap without munmap will cause leak after process exits or terminals

Tags: c, linux, gcc, memory-leaks, mmap

there is the code about alloc mem via mmap

`void *ret = mmap(NULL, 4 * 1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);`

when process exits normally, the memory will be return to os ?

Comment: Can you give a bit more information of OS, compiler and language?

Comment: OS: Linux
compiler: gcc
language: c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and under `unmap`:

> The region is also automatically unmapped when the process is
>   terminated.

Which sounds very reasonable as the memory is added to the processes pages in the virtual memory which is freed upon termination.

[Opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) doesn't say anything on the subject.

If the system does not free the memory You can try to set an at_exit up to clear up any still allocated memmaps that are still valid if you can find a pointer to it.

Comment: You just saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the hard way, that *mmap()* without *munmap()* also causes a leak if the process **isn't** terminated, but just keeps on running.
In hindsight, that seems pretty evident.

While investigating a memory leak for days on end, I now realize that I shouldn't have relied entirely on Valgrind to find the cause. I was dumbfounded when Valgrind reported no leak at all, while I could just see the VSZ section of the *ps* report about my process increasing steadily.

Then after desperately Googling further, ultimately a remark [here](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/LinuxMemoryStats) put me on the right track :

> If your program is in a steady state but your VSZ keeps increasing, you have some sort of allocation leak. It may not strictly be a memory leak; you might be forgetting to unmap files or unload dynamically loaded code or something.

And as stated clearly in [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251833/mmap-and-valgrind-mmap-doesnt-increase-heap-size), Valgrind does NOT report *mmap()* leaks.